# Regression with a fuzzy nominal predictor

Tags: poisson-regression, fuzzy

I am looking at count + offset (rate) data that can be grouped into historical periods, but the borders between the periods are fuzzy, as in the specific year that delineates one period from another is actually a range. For example, the "Gilded Age" could be said to run from 1875-1885 to 1895-1900. The Progressive Era would begin in 1895-1900 and run to 1916-1919. Events occur that could fall into both eras, since the boundaries between the eras are fuzzy. How could this be modeled?

Comment: How do you define fuzzy?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. So the intervals change from year to year?

Comment: No. The lengths of the periods are fuzzy and the borders between them overlap. The periods could also be called "eras" and are multi-year.

Comment: as thoughts for foods for you (not exactly appropriate): https://academic.oup.com/restud/article-abstract/85/2/999/4096388